# Поиск пути на карте

Tags: поиск, поиск-пути

Понабилось мне, значит, такая штука, как поиск путей на полу-статической карте.
Ясен пень первым делом пошел в поиск. Много чего интересного, но как-то слишком муторно всё. Хотя думаю есть и более простые алгоритмы, но я дальше не пошел и решил сам поумничать.

Нарисовал вот такую карту (кстати, все картинки кликабельны ;-) ):

[image: карта]
<sub>(источник: [upyourpic.org](http://upyourpic.org/images/201301/635usmkjsw_tn.jpg))</sub>

Как видно, карта ограничена определенными размерами и на ней есть закрашенные многоугольники - ака "непроходимые места". Также на карту нанесены графы. Графы служат основным путем, к которому и будет цепляться наш "проходимец".

Так вот, допустим есть пример:

[image: карта]
<sub>(источник: [upyourpic.org](http://upyourpic.org/images/201301/fer4w6nzqr_tn.jpg))</sub>

Как я представляю работу алгоритма:

- строим прямую от начальной точки до конечной точки (через всю карту, поверх непроходимых мест, коричневая линия)
- ищем точку, которая находится на прямой (коричневой), до пересечения объекта. Переходим на неё.
- От полученной точки рисуем прямую по принципу первого пункта. Ищем точку по принципу второго пункта.
- Зацикливаем.
- Если мы стоим на точке, от которой до финиша нет препятствий, то проводим прямую линию.

(Проблема 1) Вроде всё легко и просто. Но прикол в том, что точка, на которую мы перемещаемся, может быть близко, но путь длинее. А чуть дальше будет точка, которая дальше, но через неё путь короче.

Как вариант думаю - перебирать все пути до конечной цели и сравнивать их длину, но чото мне стремно становится от такого дела.

(Проблема 2) Плюс на карте будет присутствовать такая штука, как "переменная проходимость" через непроходимые места, т.е.:

[image: картинка]
<sub>(источник: [upyourpic.org](http://upyourpic.org/images/201301/e67kimvq2d_tn.jpg))</sub>

Собственно у меня тоже есть некоторые мысли, но они требуют доработки по существующим проблемам. Добавлю то, что на карте не будет непроходимых мест (т.е. не получится застрять в каком-нибудь квадрате с внутренним вырезом, из которого нельзя выйти).

Более просто: хотелось бы услышать мнения по улучшению существующего находа пути + идеи по решению проблемы 1 и 2.

Comment: Хм, а чем вам алгоритм Дейкстры не угодил?

Comment: @VladD пишут, что он не такой шустрый. По этому он почему-то отпал у меня.

Comment: @lampa: посмотрите в сторону [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) тогда.

Comment: @VladD тоже смотрел. Он отпал в виду того, что карта не разбивается на отдельные клетки, а все направления в векторном виде. Ох уж, может и неправильно говорю, но вы поймете меня. Разбивать карту на клетки тоже не горю желанием :)

Comment: @lampa: хм, но A* вроде же на графе, клетки не нужны, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD да хз, либо ступил, либо картинка смутила, которая в описании. Всё равно кажется как-то громоздко, можно же легче. Надо попробовать короче.

Comment: @lampa: Вообще-то есть такое, громоздко. Но [Википедия](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) упоминает только Дейкстру и A* вроде. Я лучше не знаю :(

Comment: offtop: в чем картинки рисованы? )

Comment: @petya руками + пост обработка в фотошопе. Потом в паинте. :)

Comment: [Задача коммивояжёра](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0) оно ?

Comment: Все картинки больше не кликабельны и не картинки ..

Answer (score 5):

Я бы порекомендовал [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). Он должен перекрывать по производительности алгоритм Дейкстры.

Исходя из дискуссии в комментариях, должен подходить.

Comment: @lampa: удачи вам!

Comment: @VladD В общем пока так: на карте есть графы. Допустим, мы ищем из одной точки в другую через препятствия. Если прямая, проведенная через всю карту от точки, до точки не задевает препятствия, что герой идет спокойно напрямую. Если же есть столкновения этой прямой с препятствиями, то находим первое препятствие. Потом находим ближайшую точку на графе от пересечение стороны препятствия и прямой (если их несколько, то проводим прямые от каждой точки, и выбираем следующую точку только ту, от которой путь до финиша по прямой самый короткий). От этой точки опять строим прямую и повторяем все действи

Comment: @lampa: если я правильно понял алгоритм, он неоптимально сработает на вот такой карте: <http://imgur.com/NrEXcse>. Алгоритм пойдёт по красной линии, а лучше было бы по синей.

Comment: @VladD забыл упомянуть, что алгоритм будет хорошо работать только на тех картах, где препятствия меньше, чем сами пути (как мне и нужно)

Comment: @lampa: для маленьких препятствий должно покатить, по идее. Я бы всё же чуть поменял алгоритм: после того, как вы находите ближайшую вершину от т. пересечения с препятствием (пусть эта вершина X), задачу можно разбить на две: от начала до X и от X до конца, их можно решить рекурсивно. (Возникает вопрос об остановке рекурсии.)

Comment: @VladD я вот как раз хочу уйти от просчета путей-ответвлений. Чтобы "быстро быстро" скрипт работал :)

Comment: @lampa: но вы же половину этого делаете? Вы по сути считаете путь от X к целевой точки рекурсивно, правильно же? [Рисунок в тему](http://i.imgur.com/mSOMBW6.png).

Comment: @VladD на вашем рисунке алгоритм выберет самый короткий путь (это синий). Вершины графов будут находиться на углах прямоугольника. В итоге всё сводится к тому, чтобы правильно точки вершин расставить на карте :)

Answer (score 1):

Нужен алгоритм поиска пути по карте, что-то вроде  [этого](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%AD%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Answer (score 0):

Я года 2 назад столкнулся с такой же проблемой когда делал игру, и сам написал алгоритм для поиска пути, потом я узнал что он называется [волновой](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC). Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Не до конца понимаю, но у меня векторный вид. Сетки, как таковой, вообще нет.